# Difference between ++i and i = 1 in a recursive function

Tags: java, recursion, binary-tree

I was trying to write a toString method with preordertraverse. Here are two functions. In preOrderTraverse there are two different outputs when I write ++depth and depth + 1.

```
public String toString()
{
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    preOrderTraverse(root, 1, sb);
    return sb.toString();
}
private void preOrderTraverse(Node<E> node, int depth, StringBuilder sb)
{
    for(int i = 1; i < depth; ++i)
        sb.append("      ");
    if(node == null)
        sb.append("null\n");
    else
    {
        sb.append(node.toString());
        sb.append("\n");
        preOrderTraverse(node.left,depth + 1, sb);
        preOrderTraverse(node.right,depth + 1,sb);
    }
}
```

This gives me this

```
  50
        30
              null
              null
        70
              null
              null
```

If I write this

```
preOrderTraverse(node.left,++depth, sb);           
preOrderTraverse(node.right,++depth,sb);
```

I get this one

```
  50
       30
            null
                 null
            70
                 null
                      null
```

Why is that happening?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`++depth` returns the value after *incrementing the value*. If you have two commands that increment a value, then that value will change between the two commands.

```
preOrderTraverse(node.left,  ++depth, sb);           
preOrderTraverse(node.right, ++depth, sb);
```

is roughly equivalent* to this:

```
depth = depth + 1;
preOrderTraverse(node.left,  depth, sb);
depth = depth + 1;           
preOrderTraverse(node.right, depth, sb);
```

* it's not exactly equivalent at least because the operation is evaluated just after `node.left` and before the evaluation of `sb` (assuming the Java interpreter follows a left-to-right rule for function argument evaluation).

Answer (score 2):

In

```
preOrderTraverse(node.left,depth + 1, sb);
preOrderTraverse(node.right,depth + 1,sb);
```

both recursive call get the same value for the 2nd argument, since `depth + 1` doesn't change the value of the local variable `depth`.

In

```
preOrderTraverse(node.left,++depth, sb);           
preOrderTraverse(node.right,++depth,sb);
```

The second recursive call is passed a value larger by 1 than the value passed to the first call, since `++depth` increments the value of the local variable `depth`.

The former seems to be the correct way.

Answer (score 0):

what actually is happening is that the value changes(++depth) and doesn't get back to the value before after returning but in depth +1 value doesnt change after returning it has it previous value

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).